# Merging many xml nodes with same name into one field in postgres

Tags: xml, postgresql

This is part of my xml

```xml
<section-rodzaj-wsparcia>
  <rodzaj-wsparcia>
    <control-rozpoczecie-wsparcia>2022-11-19</control-rozpoczecie-wsparcia>
    <control-zakonczenie-wsparcia>2022-11-21</control-zakonczenie-wsparcia>
  </rodzaj-wsparcia>
  <rodzaj-wsparcia>
    <control-rozpoczecie-wsparcia>2022-11-15</control-rozpoczecie-wsparcia>
    <control-zakonczenie-wsparcia>2022-11-16</control-zakonczenie-wsparcia>
  </rodzaj-wsparcia>
</section-rodzaj-wsparcia>
```

It could have multiple `<rodzaj-wsparcia>` nodes
And this is my postgres script

```
select xmlt.* 
from orbeon_form_data ofd
  cross join lateral XMLTABLE
  (
    '/form/section-uczestnicy/section-uczestnicy-iteration/section-uczestnik'
    PASSING by ref "xml"
    columns
      "uczestnik_data_rozpoczecia_udzialu_we_wsparciu" text path    'section-rodzaj-wsparcia/rodzaj-wsparcia/control-rozpoczecie-wsparcia/first',
      "uczestnik_data_zakonczenia_udzialu_we_wsparciu" text path    'section-rodzaj-wsparcia/rodzaj-wsparcia/control-zakonczenie-wsparcia/first'
  ) xmlt
where ofd.form='Monitorowanie_Uczestnikow' 
  and ofd.form_version=1;
```

Now in script i choose values from only first `<rodzaj-wsparcia>` node, but if there's many `<rodzaj-wsparcia>` nodes I want to get both values separated with |.

For example in this case
`uczestnik_data_rozpoczecia_udzialu_we_wsparciu` value should be `"2022-11-19 | 2022-11-15"` and `uczestnik_data_zakonczenia_udzialu_we_wsparciu` should be `"2022-11-21 | 2022-11-16"`

Do You have any advice how to iterate over this nodes in postgres and put values into one field separated with '|'?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find that if I use xml field type instead of text i got two values, but surrounded by node names